# fullcalendar date formatting

Tags: date, internationalization, format, fullcalendar

I have a rails application that uses fullcalendar.  Sites have a language setting that is passed into fullcalendar.  In the full calendar demo for languages (see http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.6.1/demos/languages.html), the language setting determines the date formatting, in this case for the week view of the calendar in German, or 'de'

[image]

I'm using the same files in the application but I'm not seeing the same format when the calendar language is set to 'de':

[image]

Somewhere there is a file that is setting the format and overriding what fullcalendar would normally do.  It's hard tracing things with everything minified so I dropped in the fullcalendar.js version and the documentation suggests that columnFormat is the attribute that determines the format here and this line in that file may be doing the formatting here "this.colHeadFormat = this.view.opt('columnFormat') || this.computeColHeadFormat();" at around line 5134, but I'm still not able to trace it.  Can anyone give me suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can watch [this](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/titleFormat/)

```
[...]
header : {
            left : 'prev,next today',
            center : 'title',
            right : 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
titleFormat: YOUR FORMAT
```

Hope that will help :)